# Why is Turkish Lira symbol ₺ replaced with ? in SQL server 2008 database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, unicode, character-encoding

Any idea why the Turkish Lira symbol is replaced by a question mark when I insert it in a table in the database. See the image below

[image]

Comment: is the field varchar or nvarchar??

Comment: You do have the table configured to allow UTF-8, correct?

Comment: That fiels is a varchar

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is not a font issue. This is a Unicode (UTF-16) vs 8-bit Code Page character set issue (i.e. `NVARCHAR` vs `VARCHAR`). The character you are trying to use does not exist in the particular Code Page indicated by the default Collation of the DB in which you are executing this query. The Code Page used by the DB's default Collation is relevant here since your string literal is *not* prefixed with an upper-case "N". If it was, then the string would be interpreted as being Unicode and no conversion would take place. But since you are passing in a non-Unicode string, it will be forced into the current DB's default Collation's Code Page as the query is parsed. Any characters not available in that Code Page, and not having a Best-fit mapping, get turned into "?".

You can run the following to see for yourself:

```
SELECT '₺';
PRINT '₺';
```

It both prints AND displays in the results grid as `?`

If you want to see what character SQL Server thinks it is, run the following:

```
SELECT ASCII('₺');
```

And it will return: `63`

If you want to see what character has an ASCII value of 63, run this:

```
SELECT CHAR(63);
```

And it will return: `?`

Now run this:

```
SELECT N'₺';
PRINT N'₺';
```

This will both print and display in the results grid correctly.

To see what character value the symbol really is, run the following:

```
SELECT UNICODE(N'₺'), UNICODE('₺');
```

This will return: `8378` and `63`

But isn't `63` the question mark? Yes. That is because *not* prefixing the string literal `'₺'` with a capital "N" tells SQL Server that it is `VARCHAR` and so it gets translated to the default unknown character.

Now, if you were to execute this `VARCHAR` version in a DB that had a Collation tied to a Code Page that had this character, then it would work even when not prefixing the string literal with an upper-case "N". However, at the moment, I cannot find any Code Page used within SQL Server that supports this character. So, it might be a Unicode-only character, at least at far as SQL Server is concerned.

The way to fix this is:

1. Change the datatype of the field to `NVARCHAR` (I see in a comment on the question that the field is currently `VARCHAR`). If the field is `VARCHAR` then even if you use the `N` prefix on the string, the character will still get stored as `?`, unless the Code Page specified by the Collation of the column supports this character, but again, I think this might be a Unicode-only character.
2. Change your `INSERT` statement to prefix the string field with a capital "N": `(73, 4, N'(3) ₺')`. Even if you change the field to `NVARCHAR`, if you don't prefix the string with `N` then SQL Server will translate the character to `?` first and then insert the `?`. This is because the query gets parsed before it gets executed, and parsing (for non-Unicode string literals and variables) is done in the Code Page of the DB's default Collation

Comment: A much better answer than mine. Good write-up

Comment: I changed the insert statement to (73, 4, N'(3) ₺') and I was able to insert the Turkish lira symbol in the table. Note that the column type remained varchar. No when I query the database and load the results in a web browser I still get '?' Is this because the column is not NVarchar? Or is  it due to something else? Keep in mind that the table no longer has ?

Comment: @AlanFord : You are saying that you do a `SELECT setting_value_desc` on that table and you see the `'(3) ₺'` in the results grid? If so, are you sure that the field is `VARCHAR`. You can do `sp_help lu_panel...` to make sure. Also run this to see what character it really is: `SELECT *, UNICODE(SUBSTRING(setting_value_desc, 5, 1)) FROM lu_panel...`

Comment: My bad, the column was NVARCHAR, so the symbol gets stored properly  in the table. However, the browser still displays ?

Comment: @AlanFord : ok that makes more sense (i.e. that the field is NVARCHAR), else it would be hard to explain how the correct character got stored ;-). As far as display goes, that is a browser encoding issue (similar to the now fix DB encoding issue). How are you viewing the results? You probably need to explicitly set the encoding of the HTML page: "Content-Type" meta tag (http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_charactersets.asp). That w3cschools page says that UTF-8 is the default but try that first and then try UTF-16.

Answer (score 1):

Probably for the same reason my browser isn't displaying it in the title for this question: It isn't in the application's character set (or maybe not supported by the font).

In this case, my browser shows some numbers in a box (denoting the character code).
SQL-server is translating it to a known character instead.

Ensure you're storing it in a field that supports the character in it's character set (I think UTF-8 is sufficient)